# Instead having a base.html in global templates directory , template does not exist error is coming

Tags: python, django, web

[image: Error page description]

[image: Project direcotry structure and code]

[image: Settings file code]

I am not able to extend base.html inside templates folder in app 'todo'. base.html is present inside templates folder in main directory.
base.html is present in templates folder but it's showing in the error this file is not existing in source folder.

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR , "templates")
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

this is setting.py updated.

Comment: Likely the `base.html` is in a directory that is *not* in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, so Django will never look there.

Comment: Please Share you settings.py file configuration.

Comment: shared settings.py config

Comment: try using this `BASE_DIR =[os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))],` and then inside `TEMPLATE DIRS` call  `BASE_DIR`

Comment: I think ,i am doing the same thing if not then how it is diffrent from my way.